add_two_ints_client() doesn't stop blocking
I am following this ROS tutorial to create a server and client: https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29. However, when I run the code, I get this:
$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
Ready to add two ints.

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_client.py 1 3 
Requesting 1+3
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cindy/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/add_two_ints_client.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/cindy/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_client.py", line 29, in <module>
    print("%s + %s = %s"%(x, y, add_two_ints_client(x, y)))
  File "/home/cindy/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_client.py", line 10, in add_two_ints_client
    rospy.wait_for_service('add_two_ints')
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 164, in wait_for_service
    time.sleep(0.3)
KeyboardInterrupt

I have to interrupt, because it doesn't stop running otherwise. It seems to be that wait_for_service keeps blocking. Any suggestions?
I am using Noetic and my OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
Edit: when I originally made this post, I was using a virtual machine on a Mac. I am now doing this on a different computer (dual booted, still Noetic and Ubuntu 20.04) and I'm still having this exact issue.
Edit 2: the problem was that I wasn't running the service and client at the same time.
